# Unable to locate WebElements mobile and message box using XPath for the sites 160by2.com and way2sms.com

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Unable to locate WebElements for the mobile and message box using XPath for the sites 160by2.com and way2sms.com

HTML for 160by2.com:

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="ui-autocomplete-input" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number or Name" id="BPLZWI" name="BPLZWI" onfocus="javascript:show('contacts');" type="text">
<textarea onkeyup="javascript:countChars();" onkeydown="javascript:countChars();" onfocus="javascript:show('msgs');" id="sendSMSMsg" name="sendSMSMsg" cols="48" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your message" class="sms-msg-tex"></textarea>
```

I extracted the XPath expressions below but they fail (but the Selenium IDE identifies the XPath)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/input[@placeholder='Enter Mobile Number or Name' and @id=@name]")).sendKeys(s1);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@placeholder='Enter your message' and @id=@name]")).sendKeys(s2);
```

HTML for way2sms.com:

```
<input type="text" onchange="javascript:dispLocMob(this);" onkeydown="javascript:dispLocMob(this);" onkeyup="javascript:dispLocMob(this);" value="" maxlength="10" placeholder="Mobile Number" name="mobile" id="mobile">
<textarea onkeyup="javascript:countChars('message', 'msgLen', 140)" onkeydown="javascript:countChars('message', 'msgLen', 140, 'sndsms')" rows="5" cols="45" name="message" placeholder="Type your message here or use SMS greetings" id="message"></textarea>
```

I extracted the XPath expressions below but they fail (but Selenium IDE identifies the XPath)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='mobile' and @placeholder='Mobile Number']")).sendKeys(s1);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@id='message' and @name='message']")).sendKeys(s2);
```

I am passing parameters to textboxes and textarea after reading from an Excel file.

Comment: Each of these elements has an ID... did you try using that? You should generally avoid XPath in favor of the more standard methods. You can read more on the Selenium wiki.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ID and class attributes at first, xPath/CSS after (in case that you're not able to write selector with ID/Class attributes).

In your case (160by2.com):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("BPLZWI")).sendKeys(s1);
driver.findElement(By.id("sendSMSMsg")).sendKeys(s2);
```

Analogically you're able to use ID for your second website (way2sms.com)

Answer (score 0):

Place holder value will change when you enter input. So you have to use id, name or xpath. Xpath is the better option.

Something like this(way2sms.com):

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input(@name='mobile')").sendKeys(s1);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input(name='message')").sendKeys(s2);
```

or

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input(@id='mobile')").sendKeys(s1);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input(@id='message')").sendKeys(s2);
```